# Is there a method, in visual studio forms, that runs when the user clicks on a new position inside of a textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, forms

Right now, I'm currently working on a C# project where I'm replicating Notepad. Right now, I'm trying to implement the "Ln 0, Col 0" feature in the status bar in Notepad, so the user knows where they're at in the Notepad. Here's my code for updating the status bar label:

```cs
// Updates the status bar label to display the row and column the user's on
private void UpdateRowColStatusBar()
    => CurrentRowAndCol_StatusLabel_NotepadNoteEditor.Text = "Ln "
       + (TextBody_NotepadNoteEditor.GetLineFromCharIndex(TextBody_NotepadNoteEditor.SelectionStart) + 1)
       + ", Col "
       + (TextBody_NotepadNoteEditor.SelectionStart - TextBody_NotepadNoteEditor.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine() + 1);
```

However, I'm not sure how I can implement this method into my form so that it'll run whenever the user updates the text box. I've figured out how to run this method when the user changes the text inside of the text box (via the `TextBox_TextChanged` method), but I have yet to find a method that runs when the user "clicks" on a new spot in the text box. I've already tried the `TextBox_Click` method, which doesn't work BTW.

I would really appreciate it if anyone knows the answer to my question, and have a great day.

Just in case I didn't make what feature I wanted to implement clear, I have a photo of what I'm trying to do below:
[image]

Comment: I don't think there is an event that tells you that. But there is the SelectionStart property that tells you the position of the caret. So you could regularly check the value of that property in the background and update your statusbar. Be aware the position given is just the count of chars from the start of the text. You need to calculate rows/columns from that first.

Comment: You can update on `KeyDown`, `KeyUp`, `KeyPress`, `MouseDown`, `MouseUp`, `MouseClick`, and `MouseDoubleClick`, and as you already discovered there are several others like `TextChanged`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind everyone, I've figured it out!

So in order to do this, you simply need to implement the `UpdateRowAndCol()` method that I wrote into a `YourTextBoxName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` and `YourTextBoxName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` methods. **HOWEVER** you need to make sure that your TextChanged and Click methods are initialized in the `InitializedComponent()` method.

The file should be named `ProjectName.Designer.cs`, and then look for these two lines:

```cs
// 
// RichTextBox
// 
...
this.RichTextBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TextBody_NotepadNoteEditor_TextChanged);
this.RichTextBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.TextBody_NotepadNoteEditor_Click);
```

If you have these methods initialized, you should be able to do a Find Reference command on them (highlight method name, then do **ctrl + k, then r**) and see that your method's referenced inside of the `InitializeComponent()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create an event handler for every event that could possibly move the current position, or you can use a [`RichTextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox) instead and use the [`SelectionChanged` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionchanged). It still has the `SelectionStart` property, so your code will still work.